# How do I check what's going on after every instruction at runtime?

Tags: python, visual-studio, debugging

I'm new to the whole IDE thing. I code on competitive coding websites and practice there.
So my question is, what tools are available to check what variable holds what at each instruction during runtime and where the program flow is, in order to debug?
I have VS code installed idk if it has that feature.

Comment: Python's [trace module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/trace.html) is an option.

Comment: There's also python's [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers). VS Code [logpoinsts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_logpoints) are useful even though its not for every line. Search "python trace program execution" and "python profiler" for more options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You're using Python. Then in order to be able to debug Your program You would need to:

1. Install [VS Code Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)
2. Visit the official Debugging documentation provided by the extension [Official Debugging documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)

But If You're debugging a single file and You installed the Python support for VS Code it should be as simple as pressing F5 to start debugging.

Please note that if You require any packages installed in order to perform successful debugging You either need to create a Virtual Environment using Python [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and activate it everytime You work on a specific project. Or You can install the packages globally (which is not ideal)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kaszanas!

Comment: @CoderAlan If this will solve Your problem and is a sufficient enough answer. Please mark it as accepted. Otherwise I am happy to provide further explanation up to my knowledge.

Comment: I think I got enough, I can search the rest:) there's this cool down, I'll mark the question resolved once the cooldown is over:)